# Can a Python package contain a module written in C or C++?

Tags: python, python-3.x, namespaces, package, python-module

I`m quite new to python packages and I just want to know if a Python package can contain modules written in other languages as for example C or C++.

Comment: have you actually tried googling this query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course, here is a lot of python packages written in other languages https://pypi.org/

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, some of the packages are written in c and c++ in order to improve speed. For eg open cv is written in c++.